# How to access to given element in Json

Tags: javascript

I am new to Json. please tell me how to access following element. this is my Json

```
var data = {"student":[{"fname":"mad", "sname":"cha"}, {"fname":"sun", "sname":"ban"}, {"fname":"sha", "sname":"kiri"}]};
```

so how I access to the `"mad"`value.

actually this is what I trying to do

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

<script>
    function click_me(){
        var data = {"student":[{"fname":"mad", "sname":"cha"}, {"fname":"sun", "sname":"ban"}, {"fname":"sha", "sname":"kiri"}]};
        localStorage.setItem('my_name',data);
        alert('OK');
    }

    function show_me(){
        var x = localStorage.getItem('my_name');
        x = x.student[0].fname;
        alert(x);
    }
</script>

</head>
<body>
  <input type="button" name="btn" value="Click" onclick="click_me()">
  <input type="button" name="btn" value="show_me" onclick="show_me()">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's

```
var yourValue = data.student[0].fname
```

By the way, this isn't JSON but a plain javascript object. [JSON](http://www.json.org/) is a string based interchange format.

---

**EDIT following your edit.**

localStorage only stores strings. That's why `getItem` gives you a string in which you can't find your "mad".

Here's what you can do :

```
function click_me(){
    var data = {"student":[{"fname":"mad", "sname":"cha"}, {"fname":"sun", "sname":"ban"}, {"fname":"sha", "sname":"kiri"}]};
    localStorage.setItem('my_name', JSON.stringify(data));
    alert('OK');
}

function show_me(){
    var x = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('my_name')||"{}");
    x = x.student[0].fname; // it would be cleaner to test x.student exists
    alert(x);
}
```

Comment: @dystroy is right. The problem is localStorage. Here is one related post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage store json with localStorage. But you don't need to use localStorage at all.

Answer (score 1):

Access the value as follows:

```
var firstName = data.student[0].fname;
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/N8bSk/

Answer (score 1):

you can do this by

```
  var yourValue = data.student[0].fname
```